# probability concatenation characters?

Tags: java

if i have 'a' , 'b' , 'c' the probability is :

```
**
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
**
```

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.in"));
    int x = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()) ;
    String [] ar = new String[x] ;
    String output = "";


    for(int i =0 ; i< ar.length ; i++)
    {

        ar[i] = input.readLine() ;
    }

    for(int y = 0 ; y < ar.length ; y++)
    {
        for(int z =y ; z < ar.length ; z++){


        output = output.concat(ar[z]) ;

        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
```

maybe more anyway how can I coding this ?

Comment: Read on permutation/combination.

Comment: What's the question? I didn't understand a thing from it.

Comment: By *"the probability is"*, do you perhaps mean *the permutations are*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to get a list of anagrams. Recursion will give you a neat solution. Here is how you can approach your problem:

1. To make an anagram of n-letters word you can make an anagram of the rightmost n-1 letters, so to make an anagram for word 'user' you can fix the letter `u` and make all possible anagrams of `ser`.
2. After that you 'rotate' the word, so 'user' becomes 'seru'.
3. Repeat the process until you rotate all the letters, and come back to 'user'.

The base case is one-letter word: its anagram is the word itself.

P.S. For in-depth explanation on topic of recursion and, specifically, recursive approach to anagrams' generation you can read the 6-th chapter of Lafore'a "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java".